# Allow contributors to moderate comments comments on posts they write

Tags: comments, capabilities, moderation

I run a multi-author wordpress site where we have a large number of contributors that can write articles, which are published after they are reviewed by an editor. (This is all standard wordpress behaviour).

What I would like to do is give the contributors the ability to moderate comments on the posts which they write, but not on posts written by other people. I haven't found a way of doing this, either with a code snippet or plugin and am hoping that someone here knows how to make this work.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I am running multisite.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simple by using plugin [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). It is very easy to use.

Comment: Bad news. This doesn't work. I think the problem lies in the fact that contributors don't have the `edit_posts` capability after the post has been published, and 'edit_posts' is required for 'moderate_comments' to work. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: After some recent experiences with the unfiltered_html capability I think the fact that I am running wordpress multisite might be important. I'll edit the original question to reflect this

Comment: oh, then this plugin is not useful for you.

Comment: Did some more testing and it doesn't work in single site wordpress installations, so it isn't a wordpress multisite issue. Contributors with the `moderate_comments` capability can only moderate comments when they have the ability to edit the post. This isn't particularly useful since contributors have no ability to edit a published post. This is why achieving what I want would be easy if we were dealing with authors, since they can always edit their own posts.

Comment: In looking into map_meta_cap I found this talk by Erick Hitter and at 9:30 minutes he says that the fact that `moderate comments` is tied into `edit_posts` is a huge PITA.
 
 http://wordpress.tv/2013/07/07/erick-hitter-the-power-of-wordpress-roles-and-capabilities-understanding-map_meta_cap/